# Transaction Security ApiEvent Condition Value

Tags: transaction-security-policy

I am trying to use [Transaction Security Policy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/enhanced_transaction_security_policy_types.htm) to block some API requests using [ApiEvent policies](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/enhanced_transaction_security_policy_types_api.htm).
But I am struggling to find out what could be the valid value for the conditions below:

1. API Type
2. Client
3. Elapsed Time (what is the time unit?)
4. Platform
5. Queried Entities
6. Query

I can basically enter the value for the fields above in free text.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_api.htm

Comment: the best way to approach this is to use SOQL on the EventLog object for one day, find the CSV for the ApiEvent type and download to see what the values look like